# How do I add a picture in the background of a start button with the button being centered

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to add a image to the background of a button that is centered.
Instead the image is not showing up and the button is in the top left corner.

I tried to at least see the picture and tried copying directly from the png file and tried "golfcourse.png" I also tried compound=left,and compound=Top

CODE:

```
from tkinter import *
import os

class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master,width=300,height=85)
        self.grid(sticky="NSEW")
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.photo=PhotoImage("file=C:/Users/Tyler/Documents/Sumative/New folder/golfcourse.png")
        self._button = Button(self, text = "Start", image=self.photo, compound=LEFT,command = self._openFile,width=175,height=60)
        self._button.grid(sticky="NSEW")
    def _openFile(self):
        os.startfile('Inset file name')

root = Tk()
root.title("Shooter")
root.geometry("1600x950")

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's in the upper-left corner because you're not specifying a row and column, so it defaults to 0,0 in this case.

As for the image not showing up, you are not specifying the path properly. the `file=` part needs to be outside of the quotes:

```
self.photo=PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/Tyler/Documents/Sumative/New folder/golfcourse.png")
```

Comment: Thank You so much I really do appreciate it!